# Juro composto com switch e [de preferência] sem break em cada caso

Tags: java, eclipse

Olá. Tenho a tabela abaixo, que calcula juros sobre juros [0,5% ao mês, cumulativos] e gostaria de fazê-la com `switch` e [de preferência] sem `break` em cada caso. Também queria que o case começasse pela última parcela (`case 12:`, no caso).

```
par-    valor 
cela   a pagar
1    R$ 100,00 
2    R$ 105,00 
3    R$ 110,25 
4    R$ 115,76 
5    R$ 121,55 
6    R$ 127,63 
7    R$ 134,01 
8    R$ 140,71 
9    R$ 147,75 
10   R$ 155,13 
11   R$ 162,89 
12   R$ 171,03
```

Cheguei a uma solução muito "rústica" [pra não dizer "idiota"], que resolveu o problema, mas que ficou pedreirona demais:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwitchExercicio003 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Qual parcela você está pagando? De 1 a 12");
    int parcela = leitor.nextInt();
    double valor = 100.00;
    double taxa = 1.05;
    double case2 = valor * taxa; 
    double case3 = case2 * taxa;
    double case4 = case3 * taxa;
    double case5 = case4 * taxa;
    double case6 = case5 * taxa;
    double case7 = case6 * taxa;
    double case8 = case7 * taxa;
    double case9 = case8 * taxa;
    double case10 = case9 * taxa;
    double case11 = case10 * taxa;
    double case12 = case11 * taxa;

    switch (parcela) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + valor);
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + case2);
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + case3);
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + (case4));
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + (case5));
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + (case6));
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + (case7));
        break;
    case 8:
        System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + (case8));
        break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + (case9));
        break;
    case 10:
        System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + (case10));
        break;
    case 11:
        System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + (case11));
        break;
    case 12:
        System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + (case12));
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Oops, digite um número entre 1 e 12!");
    }

}

}
```

O professor disse que dava pra fazer exatamente como mencionei no título do post, mas não consegui chegar nem perto disso.
Agradeço desde já pela ajuda.
Abraço.

Comment: Por que gostaria de fazer com `switch`? Não seria melhor fazer do jeito certo? Está com alguma dificuldade específica?

Comment: O fato é que estou começando a programar faz apenas 1 mês. Esse exercício é muito mais de lógica dentro do `switch` do que de lógica apenas. Foi um desafio do professor.

Comment: Mas "aprender" usar uma lógica onde não se deve usar essa lógica é desaprender.

Answer (score 1):

Seria mais fácil criar um método que calcule os [juros](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juro#Juros_compostos), segue código de exemplo:

```
public class TesteJuros {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", calcularJuros(5, i, 100)));
        }
    }

    public static double calcularJuros(double taxa, int mesesDecorridos, double valor) {
        // formula para calculo de juros compostos
        double multiplicador = Math.pow(1.0 + taxa / 100.0, mesesDecorridos) - 1.0;
        return valor + multiplicador * valor;
    }
}
```

Abcs!

Comment: Muito legal. Acho que entendi, mas "oficialmente" ainda não aprendi o `for`. De qualquer modo, me pareceu mais fácil usar esse método principalmente se isso estiver dentro de um código maior, que combine outras operações com juros e tal. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```java
switch (parcela) {
    default:
        System.out.println("Oops, digite um número entre 1 e 12!");
        break
    case 12:
        valor *= taxa;
    case 11:
        valor *= taxa;
    case 10:
        valor *= taxa;
    case 9:
        valor *= taxa;
    case 8:
        valor *= taxa;
    case 7:
        valor *= taxa;
    case 6:
        valor *= taxa;
    case 5:
        valor *= taxa;
    case 4:
        valor *= taxa;
    case 3:
        valor *= taxa;
    case 2:
        valor *= taxa;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + valor);
}
```

e se você realmente precisa resolver isso sem break:

```
switch (parcela) {
    default:
        valor = 0.0
    case 12:
        valor *= taxa;
    // ...
    case 2:
        valor *= taxa;
    case 1:
        if (valor > 0.0) {
            System.out.println("Você deve pagar R$ " + valor);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Oops, digite um número entre 1 e 12!");
        }
}
```

Comment: Bingo! Era bem isso mesmo. Eu tava ali olhando pro Excel e pensando "deve haver alguma operação que faça exatamente aquilo que ele está fazendo neste momento". Era um simples `*=`. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Eu mandei essa resposta porque seu problema pedia uma solução usando switch, mas se isso não é uma restrição você realmente deveria utilizar a fórmula de juros compostos que o @hlucasfranca postou.